# Resource policies and cost on AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm curious about using API Gateway resource policies to only allow a subset of IPs to access it. I am wondering, if someone outside of this IP range would spam the endpoint, would that still incur costs or do you only pay for "non-rejected" requests?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> would that still incur costs or do you only pay for "non-rejected" requests?

**You do *not* pay for rejected requests**. I have worked with the developers to confirm the code that triggers the charges executes only after the request gets past the access controls